# How to put filteration expressions in vars in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

In our [`dc.js`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) powered [`d3.js`](https://d3js.org/) chart.

Trying to concatenate a few boolean expressions inside [crossfilter's](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/)'s `filter` function by using code appending approach.

```js
var field1 = true,
  field2 = "XYZ",
  field3 = "ABC",
  field4 = 1
var filteredData = jsonObject.filter(function(d) {

  //condition 1
  if (field1 != true && field2 != "GHI") {
    var _dataFilter = d.FieldOne >= field1 &&
      d.FieldTwo <= field2 &&
      d.FieldThree == field3 &&
      d.FieldFour == field4
  }

  return _dataFilter;
});

console.log("FieldOne " + field1 + " FieldTwo " + field2 + " FieldThree " + field3 + " FieldFour " + field4);

var sourceDataForChart = crossfilter(filteredData);
```

I'm finding that `_dataFilter` is coming as **nothing** on console. By this, I mean literally nothing. No undefined, no object, no value, no function is returned. `sourceDataForChart` is the data being used by the chart

I need to implement it for a grouping requirement, there will be a lot of conditions. 
How do I do it?

Comment: What does `jsonObject` look like? This doesn't really look like a Crossfilter question, as it appears you are trying and failing to filter the data before it is put into the Crossfilter. So this is a pure Javascript issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Ethan that this is JavaScript question.

Usually you don't want functions that will return `undefined` in some circumstances, and a value in other circumstances. Your variable `_dataFilter` will only get initialized if the conditions are true - and right now the condition is false because `field1`is true.

In fact, it's only because JavaScript hoists all variables to the function scope that the variable even exists when it's returned. So maybe this is why the debugger is reporting no value.

A better organization for the code would be

```
var filteredData = jsonObject.filter(function(d) {
  var _dataFilter = false;
  // condition 1
  if (field1 != true && field2 != "GHI") {
      _dataFilter = d.FieldOne >= field1 &&
        d.FieldTwo <= field2 &&
        d.FieldThree == field3 &&
        d.FieldFour == field4
  }
  else if (/* more conditions */ ) {
       _dataFilter = /* ... */
  }
  return _dataFilter;
});
```